# Speed vs Bandwith, ISP's, misconception?

Tags: networking, package, bandwidth

A lot of ISP's sell their products saying: 100Mbit/s Speed.
However, compare the internet to a packet service, UPS for example.

The ammount of packages you can send every second(bandwith) is something different then the time it takes to arrive(speed).

I know there are multiple meanings of the term 'bandwith' so is it wrong to advertise with speed?
Wikipedia( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth_(computing) )

> In computer networking and computer science, bandwidth,[1] network
>   bandwidth,[2] data bandwidth,[3] or digital bandwidth[4][5] is a
>   measurement of bit-rate of available or consumed data communication
>   resources expressed in bits per second or multiples of it (bit/s,
>   kbit/s, Mbit/s, Gbit/s, etc.).> In computer networking and computer
>   science, bandwidth,[1] network
>   bandwidth,[2] data bandwidth,[3] or digital bandwidth[4][5] is a
>   measurement of bit-rate

This part tells me that bandwith is measured in Mbit/s, Gbit/s.

So does this mean the majority of ISP's are advertising wrongly while they should advertise with 'bandwith' instead of speed?

Comment: I think speed and bandwidth means the same. And the speed of download(receive) is usually diffrent with the speed of upload(send) depends on ISP's configuration.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer: There are several aspects on data transfer that can be measured on an amount-per-time basis; Amount of data per second is one of them, but perhaps misleading if not properly explained.

From the [network performance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latency_vs_Bandwidth) point of view, these are the important factors (quoting Wikipedia here):

- *Bandwidth* - maximum rate that information can be transferred
- *Throughput* - the actual rate that information is transferred
- *Latency* - the delay between the sender and the receiver decoding it
- *Jitter* - variation in the time of arrival at the receiver of the information
- *Error rate* - corrupted data expressed as a percentage or fraction of the total sent

So you may have a `10Mb` connection, but if 50% of the sent packages are corrupted, your final throughput is actually just `5Mb`. (Even less, if you consider that a substantial part of the data may be [control structures](http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/Course/Section4/8.htm) instead of [data payload](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payload_%28computing%29).

Latency may be affected by mechanisms such as [Nagle's algorythm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) and ISP-side buffering:

[image]

As specified in [RFC 1149](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1149.txt), An ISP could sell you a [IPoAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_over_Avian_Carriers) package with 9G bits/s, and still be true to its words, if they sent to you 16 pigeons with 32GB SD cards attached to them, average air time around 1 hour - or ~3,600,000 ms latency.